# How can I write multiple DataFrames to a CSV the same way they print?

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv, dataframe

As tool for my job I'm trying to write a code that will scrape the information from online directories. To test it, I'm using college athletic departments. I want to put them into a DataFrame and then add that DataFrame to a csv with the proper formatting.

At the moment, I can write the information from one url to a .csv no problem with all the information properly formatted into different cells; however, when I try to write more than one, .csv is written such that each individual dataframe is written such that all of the information is written in a single cell.

Here is my code:

```
urls = ["https://webberathletics.com/staff.aspx", 
"https://fordhamsports.com/staff.aspx"]

appended_data = []
for url in urls:
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.implicitly_wait(30)
  driver.get(url)


  tables = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
  df = tables
  appended_data.append(df)


  driver.close()
  print("Finished "+ url)


dfs = pd.DataFrame(appended_data) 
dfs.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Documents\test.csv')
```

When I just print the Dataframes in the for loop, it comes out with all the data from both urls

```
    tables = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
    df = tables
    print(df)
    appended_data.append(df)
```

However, when I run the entire code, this is what my csv looks like.

```
  0 1
0 0
1
```

with all the information in cells `1,0` & `0,1`

Comment: Can you provide `appended_data` rather than read_html code, it's unclear where the issue is!

Comment: If `appended_data` is a `list` of `DataFrame` objects then you probably want to use `pd.concat(appended_data)` to get a concatenated `DataFrame` object

Comment: Whenever I try `pd.concat(appended_data)` it tells me I can't do that to a list object

Comment: He means, concatenating inside the for loop. So create an empty dataframe instead of empty list `appended_data=pd.DataFrame()`, then instead of `appended_data.append(df)` use `appended_data=pd.concat([appended_data, df])`. Since you can concatenate dataframes using `pd.concat`, but not lists.